# Вывод консольного приложения в Delphi

Tags: delphi, pascal, консоль

Приветстсвую, программеры. Как можно реализовать (и можно ли) вывод консольного паскалевского приложения в Delphi? Т.е. при нажатии на кнопку, открывается консоль и оттуда уже работает код паскаля.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариантов два.
Или пишете консольное приложение изначально - для этого нужно шаманить с настройками проекта, или создаете отдельное окно и выводите в него текст.
[Вот пример результата](http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/l/aa091101a.htm), полученного по первому пути.

Comment: Благодарю за вариант. А по поводу окна никаких исходников нет? Переписывать проект уже дюже не хочется...

Comment: Эм... В самом простейшем варианте - TForm, на ней TEdit или аналогичный компонент. А затем просто пишете функцию вывода в этот TEdit своего текста. И везде, где необходимо, ее вызываете.

Comment: Понятно. Просто меню многокнопочное, для кажной кнопки писать не есть удобно, но раз вариантов не много, то будем так.

Comment: А каково изначальное видение того как должна работать программа?

Comment: Пошагово так. Открывается Форма, на ней описание приложения и кнопки. Ну это просто для граф.интерфейса, чтоб в консоли не печатать долго. При нажатии на кнопку, открывается консоль, в которой уже выполняется программа, на которую ссылается кнопка. Чтение данных для консоли уже в файлах, но это другая история

Comment: А что мешает каждую отдельную функцию меню реализовать в виде отдельной консольной (настоящей!) программы? А граф. интерфейс - это только будет лаунчер конкретной программы. Это первое. Второе - можете сами создать консоль. Для этого даже соответствующее API в винде есть. Пример <a href=http://www.halcyon.com/~ast/dload/guicon.htm>тут</a>, правда для с++, но посмотреть какие именно ф-ции используются, думаю, Вы в состоянии. А затем смотрите MSDN...

Comment: Эм, я для подобного туповат немного) Да и задание было конкретезированно, создать программу с выбором и выполнением данных функций. Что-то создавать, мне просто не хватит опыта. Само приложение - это банальный набор сортировок массивов и матриц, множеством способов. Ничего сверхъестесственного.

Answer (score 4):

Все делается намного проще.

Создаем обычное оконное приложение, кидаем на форму кнопку, два раза кликаем по ней, в обработчике пишем следующий код:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AllocConsole;      // Выделяем (создаем) консоль
  Writeln('Hello!'); // Работаем с консолью
  Readln;            // Ждем нажатия Enter перед освобождением консоли
  FreeConsole;       // Освобождаем (удаляем) консоль
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну раз так...

То пишите свой exe с формой и кучей кнопок.

Рядом с ними кладите свои exe консольные проги.

В обработчике каждой кнопки пишите

```
 ShellExecute(Handle, 'open','1.exe', nil, nil,SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Comment: хм, а это идея... попробую так, может и выйдет

Comment: Если нужно, могу написать простенькую программу для образца.

Comment: хорошо бы. Если исходники крепить нельзя, ссылайтесь на мыло: vladislav91@yandex.ru

Comment: http://www.softr.org.ua/example.rar

Comment: Оказывается, проблема решается в две минуты) Благодарю за хелп.